# MySQL privileges for roles aren't applying to users?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, permissions, role

I've done what I consider to be sufficient research with no answers to justify posting this question here.  I am attempting to grant users permission to execute certain stored procedures.  And because I have to grant permission for several of these roles, but not all of them, I've chosen to do this using roles.  But when I grant one of these roles to a test user and try to call a stored procedure, I see this error message:

```
1370 (42000): execute command denied to user 'me'@'localhost' for routine 'db.MyProc'
```

The SQL script to create a role looks like this:

```
CREATE ROLE 'MyRole';
GRANT USAGE ON db.* TO 'MyRole';
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE db.MyProc TO 'MyRole';
-- grant execute on more procedures
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And then I grant the role to the test user and set it as default:

```
GRANT MyRole TO 'me'@'localhost';
SET DEFAULT ROLE MyRole TO 'me'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Naturally, I do all of this as root.  I think that the grants have worked because of the output of SHOW GRANTS.

```
 SHOW GRANTS FOR MyRole;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for MyRole@%                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `MyRole`@`%`                           |
| GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `db`.`MyProc` TO `Contributor`@`%`| 
|(grant execute on more procedures)                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+

SHOW GRANTS FOR 'me'@'localhost';
+---------------------------------------+
| Grants for contrib@localhost          |
+---------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO `me`@`localhost`|
| GRANT `MyRole`@`%` TO `me`@`localhost`|
+---------------------------------------+
```

I have found no one else with this problem.  And nothing I read from MySQL documentation suggested that this would not work.  What is going wrong?

I'm using MySQL 8.0.11 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The problem (it seems) was that MySQL didn't like the capital letters in my procedure names.  I went though the entire script and renamed all of my procedures with lower case letters.  I updated the roles accordingly, and then it worked properly.

Comment: This should be a Bug in Mysql. When no roles are active on the account, procedures with capital letters are handled correclty. When a role is active, the user is not permitted to use procedures with capital letters.